# Как добавить обработчик события для нескольких разных элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, события

Есть такой код:

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red')
});
```

Как модифицировать код так, чтобы задать стили не только для `<input>`, но и, к примеру, для `<label>`? Чтобы при этом не пришлось дублировать весь код.

Answer (score 6):

Вот так:

```js
$('input, label').on('click',function(){
$(this).css('color','red')
});
```

Comment: куда практичнее классами оперировать а не манипулировать непосредственным css в js-коде